# How to test Dao?

Tags: testing, junit, dao

I have a method that returns a list of groups for a given id of competence

```
public List<Group> showGroups(int CompetenceId) {

Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Group where competence_id = :id");
query.setParameter("id", CompetenceId);
List<Group> groups = query.getResultList();

return groups;
}
```

How to test this method?

Answer (score 1):

Fill your database with a well-defined set of data, then call your method, and see if the list of groups that it returns is what it should return, based on the well-defined set of data.

Shameless plug: [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/) is a cool, free, open-source library that helps in setting up your database before executing tests.

Comment: I tried to use DbSetup to populate the database, but it did not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990140/dbsetup-populate-the-database

Answer (score 0):

you either have to use Easy Mock to create mock classes  and if you spring in your code then you will have to annotate the test class with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:config/config.xml")
```

This seems to be a hard way to do for the DAO classes.

The second option will be to override the DAO framework in your JUNit itself.

```
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate() {
        public int update(String sql)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    };
    dao.setJdbcTemplate(template);
```

As shown above in case of the JdbcTemplate you will have to do it for the Criteria Queries in hibernate.