# DbSetup populate the database

Tags: database, junit4, populate

I tried to use to DbSetup to populate the database, but it did not work

class CommonOperations {

```
public static final Operation DELETE_ALL = 
        deleteAllFrom("ACH_GROUP");

public static final Operation INSERT_REFERENCE_DATA =
        sequenceOf(
            insertInto("ACH_GROUP")
```

.columns("ID", "CLOSED", "NAME", "OPENED", "COMPETENCE_ID", "LASTMODIFIEDDATE", "uuid")
                    .values(1, "", "JAVA", "", 1, "", "")
                    .build());
}

public class CompetenceDaoImplementationTest {

```
private static String username = "sa";
private static String password = "12345";
private static String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB_Achi";

// the tracker is static because JUnit uses a separate Test instance for every test method.
private static DbSetupTracker dbSetupTracker = new DbSetupTracker();

@Before
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    Operation operation =
        sequenceOf(
            CommonOperations.DELETE_ALL,
            CommonOperations.INSERT_REFERENCE_DATA);

        // without DataSource
        DbSetup dbSetup = new DbSetup(new DriverManagerDestination(URL, username, password), operation);

     // use the tracker to launch the DbSetup.
        dbSetupTracker.launchIfNecessary(dbSetup);
    }

@Test
public void testShowGroups() {
    dbSetupTracker.skipNextLaunch();
}
```

Comment: Be specific. How did it not work? What happens?

Comment: com.ninja_squad.dbsetup.DbSetupRuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter metadata not available for the given statement
 at com.ninja_squad.dbsetup.DbSetup.launch(DbSetup.java:123)
 at com.softserve.edu.dao.CompetenceDaoImplementationTest.prepare(CompetenceDaoImplementationTest.java:47)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 ...

Comment: Read http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/user-guide.html#metadata-and-mysql. Make sure you use a recent JDBC driver. AFAIK, the latest SQLServer JDBC driver does support parameter metadata: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379020.aspx.